# print two digit numbers which are less than or equal to 56 and the sum of digits is greater than 10 JAVA

Tags: java

why the following method doesn't work for printing two digit numbers which are less than or equal to 56 and the sum of digits is greater than 10 in JAVA

```
        for (int i = 10; i <= 99; i++) {
        String str = Integer.toString(i);
        int sum = (str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(1));
        if (sum > 10 && sum<=56) {
            System.out.println("The first operation " + sum);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Because you print `sum` instead of `i`

Comment: What do you expect to get? And what do you get?

Comment: Third line returns sum of `char` values, not digits.

Comment: why you increment i until 99 when you already know than your i shouldn't be bore than 56; for (int i = 10; i <= 56; i++) ... and remove the <=56 check from if ; if (sum > 10)...

Comment: The answer to everything is *debugging*. Use a debugger, step through your code, see what it does and think about what it should do.

Comment: Also note that charAt() returns the character which - for historic reasons - also can be used as an integer in which case it is the ascii code of the character, not the numeric value.  For example  "0" is a 48, and "1" is a 49.

Comment: I know this a duplicate many times over, I am just having trouble finding a good one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third line: `int sum = (str.charAt(0) + str.charAt(1));` is one of the problems. When `i` is `10`, `str.charAt(0)` evaluates the the character `1` which has ascii value `49` and `str.charAt(1)` evaluates to the character `0` which has ascii value `48` producing a sum of `97` instead of the desired `1`.

Instead you could use the modulus operator to strip-off the digits as needed. For example: `int sum = ( i / 10 ) + (i % 10);`.

*also, the range of `i` in your `for` loop should be adjusted as other users have commented.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know any number greater than 56 won't pass your criteria, you need to change your loop to go from 10 to 56. Thus, you can exclude the second part of the if statement. Change the for loop to:

```
    for (int i = 10; i <= 56; i++) {
```

and your if statement to:

```
    if (sum > 10) {
```

Comment: Then we would change the for loop, not the if condition, won't we?

Comment: The condition should also be changed to `if(sum > 10) {` and therefor the condition in the for loop should be `i <= 56` instead of `i<=99`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. He does the check twice and it makes more sense to just loop from 10 to 56 instead. I've updated my answer.